# Unnest and Average operation in Couchbase

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I have following structure saved in a bucket:

```
[
  {
"Grouplens_1M": {
  "genres": [
    "Thriller",
    "Drama"
  ],
  "movieId": 3952,
  "ratings": [
    {
      "rating": 4,
      "userId": 23
    },
    {
      "rating": 5,
      "userId": 36
    },
    {
      "rating": 4,
      "userId": 52
    }
  ],
  "title": "Contender, The (2000)"
    }
  }
]
```

Now I need to get all titles which are rated in average above 3. I found out, that I need to unnest ratings and then use AVG to get the average. But it was not working. After trying to figure out how to solve this problem, I came to this:

```
SELECT g.title, AVG(r_item.rating) AS avg_r
FROM Grouplens_1M AS g 
UNNEST ratings r_item
WHERE r_item > 4.0
GROUP BY g.title
```

After execution time on the query, it shows me a result. But the WHERE clause is not correct. It seems to ignore the statement as it shows me all movies with the average rating.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to filter out results based on the value of the derived average use `HAVING`.  `WHERE` would be used to limit the documents considered for the query.

Try

```
SELECT g.title, avg_r 
FROM Grouplens_1M AS g 
UNNEST ratings r_item
GROUP BY g.title
LETTING avg_r = AVG(r_item.rating)
HAVING avg_r > 4.0;
```